# Synchronizing dictionary Object in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary

This snippet is used to read a dictionary file into an ArrayList of vocabulary. The _dictionary here is a static shared variable between all threads, hence every time I touch this variable, I need to get hold on its lock (I knew that you can use Collections.synchronizedList, but for some stupid reason I didn’t use it).

However, after a while I discover a problem: 2 threads can simultaneously access the critical session inside synchronized (_dictionary). Well, this should not happen.     Can some one helps me out

```
  synchronized (_dictionary) {
_dictionary = new ArrayList<Vocabulary>();

// Fetch data from file into local dictionary
String nextLine = null;
do {
    nextLine = br.readLine();
    Vocabulary newVocabulary = Vocabulary.parseToVocabulary(nextLine);
    if (newVocabulary != null) {
        _dictionary.add(newVocabulary);
    }
} while (nextLine != null);
}
```

Comment: is `_dictionary` null before going into synchronized block?

Comment: To be able to answer this question we need more context. What is _dictionary? Qhat is its value before entering the `synchronized`-block?

Answer (score 0):

Java's synchronized(x) holds the lock at object level. If you change the value of x, you are changing your lock and you are changing _dictionary inside the synchronized section.

Let's imagine you have two threads.

Thread 1 -

- arrives to synchronized section
- _dictionary is an instance of ArrayList (instance1) and is not locked on instance1.
- goes into synchronized section
- changes _dictionary to a new instance of ArrayList (instance2)
- goes on...

Thread 2 -

- arrives to synchronized section
- _dictionary is an instance of ArrayList (instance2) and is not locked on instance2, but on instance1.
- goes into synchronized section.
- (...)

You should NOT create a new instance of the ArrayList inside the synchronized code block (you are creating a new object each time, instead of sharing it).

You can check how it works in:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html